# How to change certificate common name in iis?

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, ssl

[image]

The above image shows the error on my SSL cert when I tried to access my sharepoint website from sharepoint. I tried finding solutions online but they don't cater for SharePoint specifically.

How do I create a self-signed certificate that matches my sharepoint site? Or if its possible, **how do I change the certificate common name in my self-signed ssl certificate?**

I tried following this: http://blog.walisystemsinc.com/2012/12/setup-ssl-in-sharepoint-2013.html 
but they want to create a web application from scratch, whereas my web application has already been created, so I can't follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a self-signed certificate from SharePoint server IIS manager.

Go to root of IIS manager.

Select Create Self-Signed Certificate.

Name the certificate and then select OK

Right-click the certificate, and then select Export

Generate corresponding .cer file and configure SharePoint to use it.

For detailed steps, you could check below threads for sample.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins

http://spcaca.blogspot.sg/2013/10/create-on-premise-high-trust-provider.html